# Different output in AWS PHP SDK than in AWSCLI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-php-sdk

The primary goal that I'm trying to achieve is to iterate over my running EC2 instances in PHP.

It's really easy to get the data using a bash script, as shown below:

## Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIDEXAMPLE"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"
aws ec2 describe-instances --region="eu-west-1" --filter "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"
```

## Bash output:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "58728357357",
            "ReservationId": "r-0e0283649826935",
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupId": "sg-2fe333148",
                            "GroupName": "WEB"
                        }
                    ],
                    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-53-13-121-72.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
                    "Architecture": "x86_64",
                    "LaunchTime": "2016-07-11T08:28:23.000Z",
                    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "Ebs": {

            // ...

        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I try the following example, using the same keys, I am presented with what seems to be an unusable object - or at least the object looks like it is representing an empty data structure.

## PHP File:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$settings = [
    "version" => "latest",
    "region" => "eu-west-1",
    "credentials" => [
        "key" => "AKIDEXAMPLE",
        "secret" => "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
    ],
];

$client = new \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client($settings);
$result = $client->describeInstances([
    "Filters" => [
        [
            "Name" => "instance-state-name",
            "Value" => "running",
        ]
    ],
]);

var_dump($result);
```

## PHP Output:

What the hell am I meant to do with this AWS\Result?

```
class Aws\Result#82 (1) {
  private $data =>
  array(2) {
    'Reservations' =>
    array(0) {
    }
    '@metadata' =>
    array(4) {
      'statusCode' =>
      int(200)
      'effectiveUri' =>
      string(35) "https://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      'headers' =>
      array(5) {
        ...
      }
      'transferStats' =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something in the PHP configuration? Please can someone help point me in the right direction?

**P.S. I've masked the API keys in the above examples.**

Comment: First remove the Key ID and Access key from the question if they are in use before some one picks them up.

Comment: Also what output do you expect the PHP code should give you?

Comment: @error2007s I expect to see at least _some_ data about my instances, as I do with the bash example. Iterating `$results` doesn't give me anything - the first element is an empty array. Examples show `$results["Reservations"]` to hold the instance data, but mine is empty.

Answer (score 0):

EC2::DescribeInstances takes an array of filters, each of which has a string `Name` and an array of string `Values`. In your CLI example, you've supplied something for `Values`, whereas in your PHP example you've supplied a `Value` instead. This field is not recognized by the SDK and will be ignored. See [the SDK API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2016-04-01.html#describeinstances) for more information.

Your PHP should be updated to read:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$settings = [
    "version" => "latest",
    "region" => "eu-west-1",
    "credentials" => [
        "key" => "AKIDEXAMPLE",
        "secret" => "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
    ],
];

$client = new \Aws\Ec2\Ec2Client($settings);
$result = $client->describeInstances([
    "Filters" => [
        [
            "Name" => "instance-state-name",
            "Values" => ["running"],
        ]
    ],
]);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$result` ? What happens if you iterate over?

Comment: Also, your advice is incorrect. For `values` an array is required, for `value` a string is required. This is explained in the link you posted.